# Given a natural number n. Type all n-digit odd positive integers in descending order. (Use recursion) write on Python3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Given a natural number n. Type all n-digit odd positive integers in descending order. (Use recursion)  write on Python3

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't come up with a recursive function which would take "just" the number, say `n=7` as a running example. But given below is a function which takes the biggest such odd positive number and keep print odd positive numbers in descending order as desired.

```
def print_odd_desc(current_odd_positive, n):
    if current_odd_positive < (10**(n-1))+1:
        return
    print(current_odd_positive)
    print_odd_desc(current_odd_positive-2, n)

current_odd_positive = 10**(n)-1
print_odd_desc(current_odd_positive, n)
```